# How to filter in excel when cell has multiple items?

Tags: excel

Im looking to create a contract list for my work. We are in construction and have multiple contractor that do various jobs. I have a column for trade (meaning what kind of work they do) that I'm trying to filter out.

Is there a way that I can separate them with commas, hashtags, etc?

[image: sample of excel]

Comment: Will a powerpivot solution work?

Comment: Didn't it serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

- Select you data, click `get & Transform` tab on `DATA` menu and `from table`

[image]

- A power query window will be opened

[image]

- Right ckeck `Trade` col, click `split` `by delimiter`

[image]

- you'll get a split col like this

[image]

- select three trade cols and click `unpivot`, you'll get an output like this

[image]

- close and load back the data to excel, you'll get an desired output where you can put slicer of your choice

[image]

[image]